# If I bound the value of a variable with an operation like `min`, am I safe to make a narrowing conversion?

Tags: c, narrowing

For example, say I have the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 0x10000000
#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))

extern uint64_t external_uint64_t;
...


uint64_t wide = min(external_uint64_t, MAX_SIZE);
uint32_t narrow = (uint32_t) wide;
```

Is this well defined and guaranteed to initialize `narrow` with the smallest of the values between `external_uint64_t`, and `MAX_SIZE`?

Comment: `uint32_t narrow = min(external_uint64_t, MAX_SIZE);` suffices. In either this or the original code, the comparison is done with `uint64_t` operands and the result is converted to `uint32_t`. And the result is guaranteed to be representable, since the result is at most `0x10000000`, which is representable in `uint32_t`. Neither using an intermediate `uint64_t` variable nor explicitly converting to `uint32_t` adds anything semantically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this well defined and guaranteed to initialize narrow with the
> smallest of the values between external_uint64_t, and MAX_SIZE?

For **unsigned numbers** it is well defined by the C standard, but if the result of `min` will not fit into the unsigned integer type it will be converted the way described in the C standard.

> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> - 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value
>   can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> - 2 **Otherwise, if
>   the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding
>   or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented
>   in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.60)**

Comment: **It's safe for signed numbers as well**, since the OP specifically asked about numbers that can be represented by the new type. You bolded the wrong paragraph.

Comment: @ikegami His example could not be well considered.

Comment: It's not an example. They specifically asked if it's safe if they ensured the range is small enough. It's ludicrous to assume the `min` is not part of the question when they mentioned `min` and narrowing *everywhere*.

Comment: @ikegami them my answer is more general covering both cases